# Finding the diagonalizing matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Find a nonsingular matrix $C$ such that $C^{-1}AC$ is a diagonal matrix.
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        1 & 3  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I have found the eigenvalues to be 1 and 3. I also tried solving it by taking $C=\begin{pmatrix}
        a & b  \\
        c & d  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
and I got nowhere. What is the correct method for finding such $C$ in general?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you found the eigenvectors?

Comment: If $C^{-1} A C = D$, then $AC = CD$. You know $A$ and $D = \operatorname{diag}(3,1)$, so finding $C$ should not be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To diagonalize a matrix, we find a matrix consisting of the eigenvectors of the matrix we wish to diagonalize.

To find the eigenvectors, we must find vectors in the kernel of $A-\lambda I$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

In this case it means we need vectors in the kernels of

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
1&2
\end{bmatrix}\text{ and } 
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

For instance, we may take the vectors $\langle 2,-1\rangle$ and $\langle 0,1\rangle$ which we see to be in each kernel. We then put the eigenvectors into a matrix $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, which, along with its inverse will serve to diagonalize the matrix.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This all works because we are simply putting our original matrix into the basis consisting of its eigenvectors and we know exactly how the matrix behaves with respect to this basis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain more about the last two lines of your answer? I can see that this method works but I'm having some difficulty understanding why it works!

Comment: Basically we are just finding a system of coordinates on which the matrix behaves nicely. We know exactly where the matrix sends  $x=\langle 2,-1\rangle$ and $y=\langle 0,1\rangle$--it simply scales them. So, if we express a given vector as a linear combination of $x$ and $y$, we can see that it acts very nicely on $cx+dy$, i.e. it sends it to $cx+3dy$. Our new matrix simply expresses this fact.

Comment: Never looked at it that way! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check that $\;\binom{-2}1\;,\;\;\binom01\;$ are eigenvectors belonging to the eigenvalues $\;1,3\;$ resp., and form the matrix

$$C:=\begin{pmatrix}\!\!\!-2&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Check now that $\;C^{-1}AC\;$ is diagonal

Answer (score 1):

The method you tried is (the) a correct one. You find the eigenvalues and you put them in a diagonal matrix $D$. You write $C$ as you did, you find $C^{-1}$ via Cramer's rule (for example) and you solve the system $CAC^{-1} = D$.

You may have a calculation wrong. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize(%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C3%7D%7D)) you have a link to the solution of your problem. I'll try to give a more developed answer in a moment.

In more detail, you have:

$C = \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix}$, thus $C^{-1}= \frac{1}{ad-cb} \begin{pmatrix} d&-b\\ -c&a\end{pmatrix}$ (in virtue of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Analytic_solution)).

As the eigenvalues are $1$ and $3$, we may write:

$D = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Thus, solving the system (recall that this would not be possible if the matrix didn't diagonalize):

$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 1&3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} d&-b\\ -c&a\end{pmatrix} = (ad-cb) \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&3 \end{pmatrix}$

which is a system (I think it's even linear) of four equations and four variables and should be solvable. You shall find $a=-2$, $b=0$, $c=d=1$, that is:

$C = \begin{pmatrix} -2&0\\ 1&1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think this is an alternative method to finding the eigenvectors of the transformation!

Comment: My pleasure. Finding the eigenvectors is a much faster way though. And this method has problems when the matrix doesn't diagonalize (this can happen, for example, when two eigenvalues are repeated), because you now need the Jordan form of the matrix, not the diagonal matrix, to proceed this way.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have the eigenvalues, find the eigenvectors.

$A\xi_1=1\xi_1 \implies \xi_1 = (-2,1)^T$

$A\xi_3=3\xi_3 \implies \xi_3 = (0,1)^T$

Since you have distinct eigenvalues, these eigenvectors will be linearly independent.  Consider the matrix $C$ where the columns are the eigenvectors.  $C$ is non-singular since the columns are linearly independent.  Then $C^{-1} A C$ is diagonal.

Comment: Could you please explain why the resulting matrix is diagonal. I mean why a matrix made up from the eigenvectors diagonalizes the matrix A?

Comment: This is called the spectral decomposition, which you can read more about online.  In short, with $e_i$ being the vector with only the i-th component non-zero, we can compute $C^{-1} A C e_i = C^{-1} A \xi_i = C^{-1} \lambda_i \xi_i = \lambda_i e_i$.  This holds for any $i$, so the matrix must be diagonal.